# What does this C Pointer Code Produce? [ulong pointer -> uint]

Tags: c, pointers, uint, ulong

##### Hey Peeps,

Am currently working on porting some old C Library to C# but have a bit of trouble understanding a certain piece of Code containing Pointers.
Am not the best when it comes to C so i might be lacking some understanding.

### Heres a simplified version of what im Looking at:

```
unsigned int block[2];

// --- inside a function

unsigned int *block;       // only got access to this pointer not the array
unsigned long left, right;

// some math


*block++ = right;  // these lines are the important bit i dont quite get
*block = left;
```

now...

### What I think i got so far is:

- The first line...

  - dereferences the pointer
  - sets its value to `right`
  - steps the pointer forward by 1
- And the second line...

  - dereferences the pointer
  - sets its value to `left`

Now what i have trouble wrapping my head around is how the end result (`blocks[]`) looks.
(Sadly cant just debug it and take a peek bc I only have dont really know how id do that with a lib binary...)
Would be fairly simple if `left` and `right` were uints aswell but they are both ulongs so theres probably some sort of overwriting going on right?

Am a little confused / lost on this one...
Maybe some of you with some better C knowledge can help me out ^^

Comment: Is ```block``` ever initialized inside the function?

Comment: Hey @sj95126 should have probably mentioned that hehe, `block` is initialised before its handed to the function. @Barmar already gave me the answer i was looking for but still thanks for answering! ^^

Comment: I meant where you refer to ```unsigned int *block``` as "inside a function" - in that context, is ```block``` a parameter to the function, or a local variable? Just making sure the pointer has a valid value, or dereferencing it would be undefined behavior that might "happen" to work. But if Barmar has solved your problem, great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically doing:

```
block[0] = (unsigned int) right;
block[1] = (unsigned int) left;
```

And casting `unsigned long` to `unsigned int` simply discards the excess high order bits.